# How to pass multiple Headers in Apollo GraphQl

Tags: http, http-headers, graphql, apollo-client

I ma trying to pass multiple headers to Apollo graphQL, from Angular Client Project

```
return this.apollo.query({
        query: query,
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
        variables: {
            filterId: filterId
        },
        context: {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', token)
        }
    });
}
```

Above code works, but not the one below.

```
context: {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', token).append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
        }
```

I also tried

```
context: {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', token).set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a simple header object containing multiple keys.

```
context {
    headers: { 'Authorization': token, 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' }
}
```